# Split a string on a word in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cut

I wish to be able to split a string on a word. Essentially a multi-character delimiter.
For example,  I have a string:

`test-server-domain-name.com`

I wish to keep everything before 'domain' so the output would be:

`test-server-`

Note: I cannot cut on the '-'. I have to be able to cut before the term 'domain' as the string's format will vary but 'domain' will always be present and I will always want to capture the elements before 'domain'.

Is this possible in bash?

Comment: output is always " tested sever "? try,  grep test-server- file.txt

Comment: @Niransha That'll print the whole line.

Comment: Where to cut when you have 2 matching substrings like `my-domain-at-domain-name.com` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use awk:

```
echo test-server-domain-name.com | awk -F 'domain' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 6):

This will cut at the *first* `domain` it finds:

```
cutat=domain
fqdm=test-server-domain-name.com

res=${fqdm%%${cutat}*}
echo $res
```

Output:

```
test-server-
```

If you have multiple `domain`s in the string and want to cut on the last, use `res=${fqdm%${cutat}*}` (one `%`) instead.

---

From [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> `${parameter%word}`
> `${parameter%%word}`
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)). If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `%%` case) deleted. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 0):

Incrivel is correct.

```
$ name=test-server-domain-name.com
$ echo $name                                  
test-server-domain-name.com
$ echo $name |awk -F '-domain-name.com' '{print $1}'
test-server
```

Comment: When @incrivel is correct, you shouldn't copy his answer.